# Late Binding: Can it be achieved with object variables other than OBJECT type?

Tags: vb.net

Generally late binding happens when an instance of an OBJECT type tries to access a member of a derived class. I was wondering if this definition can be extended that is do we get late binding error when an object variable of a class tries to access a member of a more derived class. So tried the following: Instance "v" of the base class VEHICLE tries to access the MAKE property of the CAR class. MAKE is not present in VEHICLE. The compiler does not allow this but error message is not that of late Binding. It just says that "Make is not a member of Vehice". So clearly this was not late binding. Code i wrote is given below:

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim c As New Car()
        Dim v As Vehicle = New Car()
        c.Make = "Ford"  'Early Binding
        v.make = "Nissan"  'Late Binding. Hence Disallowed
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Class Vehicle
    'Some code
End Class
Class Car
    Inherits Vehicle
    Public Property Make As String
    Public Property price As Integer
End Class
```

So my question is is there a way to achieve late binding without using an instance of OBJECT type?

Comment: `v` is a `Vehicle` object. That's not Late Binding, it appears that `Vehicle` doesn't have a `make` (or `Make`) property, which instead belongs to the `Car` class. -- It's assumed that Vehicle is an abstract (`MustInherit`) class and Car derives from it. So, fix your classes and *make* use of Interfaces where required. -- To better *make* your point, post the definitions of your objects and a better description of what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: *"Generally late binding happens when an instance of an OBJECT type tries to access a member of a derived class"*. No. Late binding simply means that you access a member that does not belong to the type of the reference but does belong to the type of the object at run time. Basically, you use a variable of a base type and access a member of a derived type. For instance, you might have a `Control` variable and access the `Value` property, relying on the variable referring to a `DateTimePicker` at run time.

Comment: Why would/should the error message refer to late binding? You have `Option Strict On` so late binding is not allowed, so the compiler will simply assume you won't even attempt to use it. If a member doesn't exist on the type of the variable then the error is that the member doesn't exist, so that's what it reports. Why should it consider that you're trying to use late binding when you have explicitly stated that you're not going to use late binding by setting `Option Strict On`?

Comment: I just deleted my answer because it appears that I was wrong and under some misconceptions about late binding. I pretty much never use it and it appears that I have been making certain assumptions long enough that I considered them facts when they are not. It appears that, as you suggested in your question, late binding only works with the `Object` type. May apologies for trying to lead you astray.

Comment: Just took a quick look at the documentation and it says "[a]n object is early bound when it is assigned to a variable declared to be of a specific object type" and "an object is late bound when it is assigned to a variable declared to be of type `Object`". From the horses mouth, late binding requires the `Object` type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no problem...thanks for clarifying

Comment: If you want late binding on a variable declared with a more specific type than `Object`, you can accomplish it by casting to object for the late-binding statement e.g. `Call CObj(yourVariable).LateBoundMethod()`.

Comment: @Craig Yes. But if I need to cast a variable to OBJECT type, then it just re-establishes the conclusion that Late Binding happens only with OBJECT type variables.